# ASP.NET Core 2.0 - Options for importing external assembly views

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.0

### Project structure

The solution has the following projects:

#### `Cms`

Sdk: `Microsoft.NET.Sdk`

Output type: `Library`

Contains: `IServiceCollectionExtensions`, `IWebHostBuilderExtensions`, TagHelpers, middleware and other infrastructure code.

#### `Cms.Web`

Sdk: `Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web`

Output type: `Exe`

Contains: Razor pages, Controllers, Views, wwwroot for the CMS' pages

#### `Cms.Manual`

Sdk: `Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web`

Output type: `Exe`

Contains: Razor pages, Controllers, Views, wwwroot for the CMS' manual.

This is a sample project that uses the CMS.

### The problem

In `Cms.Manual.Startup`:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddCms();
}
```

In `Cms.Services.IServiceCollectionExtensions`:

```
public static IServiceCollection AddCms(this IServiceCollection services)
{
    // other code

    var assembly = typeof(Cms.Web.Pages.IndexModel).GetTypeInfo().Assembly;
    services
        .AddMvc()
        .AddApplicationPart(assembly)
        .AddControllersAsServices();

    return services;
}
```

This causes an exception, because the DLL can't be found. I think this is because I'm ignorant of some part of the build process for .Exe output projects.

I've verified inter-project references: all in order.

### Other attempt

Putting the views in the `Cms` project instead, using an `EmbeddedFileProvider` to serve them.

This worked, but since now all .cshtml, .js and .css files were embedded, I would have to recompile if styling or content was wrong. That grinds the UI development portion of this project to a halt.

### Other solution I can think of

Web development in `Cms.Web`, using embedded files as above, but adding some kind of build action to automatically move files from `Cms.Web` to `Cms`.

### Goal

I want to achieve two things:

- Ease for the consumer: simply `.UseCms()` and not much else
- Serve MVC from another assembly in the consuming ASP.NET Core project

What's the solution? I'll accept a way to get around the Exception.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try with my library

[AUR.NETCore.Mvc.PluginsManager](https://www.nuget.org/packages/AUR.NETCore.Mvc.PluginsManager/1.0.0#)

choose a folder in which the assemblies will be contained

use or extend `AUR.NETCore.Mvc.PluginsManager.interfaces.IPluginBase` which is an interface for the plugin

then you must add it to ConfigureServices this

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    //...
    services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);
    Plugins.Load(services); // last row
}
```

remember that the external plugin assembly must set up

```
public ViewsTypeResouces ViewsTypeResouces { get => ViewsTypeResouces.Assembly; }
```

you will find everything in the documentation

Comment: I've abandoned this project since, but thanks a lot for the suggestion!